# Woocommerce: Get current product category

Tags: woocommerce

How do I get the current product category that the user is browsing through?

I am trying to use `get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');` but this is giving me the categories for each product listed on the page. I would like to get the **current category** user is browsing through, the current product listing page.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is a one liner:

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object()->term_id;
```

or

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object()->name;
```

or

```
...
```

Comment: Great, this works for both product and post categories and terms.

Comment: `print_r( $wp_query->get_queried_object() );` to see all the available indexes -- not just `term_id`. example: `echo $wp_query->get_queried_object()->name;`

Answer (score 15):

To get the current category ID.
you have to use

```
get_queried_object();
```

The proper way for doing this is..

```
$cate = get_queried_object();
$cateID = $cate->term_id;
echo $cateID;
```

Comment: Can't believe how much time I spent searching for this simple answer. WooCommerce is deceivingly similar to vanilla WordPress. Until it isn't.

Answer (score 12):

try this :

```
        global $post;
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
        $nterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag'  );
        foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
            $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
            $product_cat_name = $term->name;
            break;
        }

       echo $product_cat_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can create shortcode [show_product_category_id], that will show product's category id. For example, while browsing a category of products, it will show this id. You can open functions.php of the theme and add this:

```
add_shortcode( 'show_product_category_id', 'show_product_category_id' );

function show_product_category_id() {
$cat = get_queried_object();
$catID = $cat->term_id;
echo $catID;
}
```